# Can I bake Nutella?

Tags: baking, dough, cookies, filling

I'm wanting to use Nutella in my cookies. However, I'm not sure if it's okay to bake Nutella under these conditions:

- Undiluted – I wouldn't mix the Nutella with any other ingredients
- Not exposed – the Nutella would be baked inside the cookie, in a pocket in the dough
- 190° Celsius (375° Fahrenheit)
- 10 minutes in the oven

So, will this work out? If not, what would I need to change to make it okay to bake Nutella?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have no experience with cookies, but I DID bake Nutella as a filling in bread-dough, and a friend of mine made nutella-cupcakes.
In neither case was there any issue, and both versions extend the 10-minute-mark.  Just let the cookies cool down some before biting into them. Hot Nutella is... well, HOT!

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you have some experience.
Thanks! :)