# how to bake with nutella without burning it?

Tags: baking, bread, chocolate, rolls

I saw another user ask this but it was 5 years ago and I cannot figure out how to DM. Dear user Layna, if you see this, I require your expertise!
I want to make rolls with Nutella filling. like cinnamon rolls but with a Nutella filling instead. The only problem is I've made hazelnut chocolate filling for my rolls before, and it burned on top, and considering Nutella is much more liquidy than the hazelnut chocolate paste fillings I've made, I am thinking the Nutella will either totally burn or change the flavor. I am not opposed to mixing the nutella with something else as long as it doesn't destroy the flavor.
My immediate assumption would be to bake them for less time, however sweet bread rolls like these typically require 20-25 minutes, and I think the nutella would burn in that time.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Related (the one hinted at, which asks about encapsulated Nutella): https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/84976/67

Comment: I think you'd need to pipe and roll carefully to keep the filling from being exposed at either end, rather than the usual cinnamon roll "bulk roll and chop" method with exposed filling. Borrow from chocolate croissant shaping / filling techniques, perhaps. Mind you, if you've made actual hazelnut chocolate filling, I don't know why you'd reach for Nutella instead.

Comment: Go to the profile of that user (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/26972/layna?tab=topactivity) and just ask in comments of some of her posts.

Answer (score 0):

Bake at 350 degrees in bread, and you'll be fine. Encase the Nutella inside of the bread and make sure no nutella is exposed. It will be slightly burnt, have a black look to it, but it tastes great. With Nutella, you want it slightly burnt like this or it will taste too dry.